# How to handle different version of pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pip

I have different version of pip in my machine ubuntu12.04 as below

```
pip     pip2    pip2.7  pip3    pip3.2
```

default pip is as below, using pip --version gives:

```
pip 7.1.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages (python 3.2)
```

I have a package name pyang, previously I have installed it using pip2.7 and it is present there, I tried using pip2.7 install pyang.. It gives

```
Requirement already up-to-date: pyang in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyang-1.6-py2.7.egg
```

I want /usr/bin/pyang to point to my installed pyang using pip for python2.7, How can we do that?

Comment: I'd recommend using virtual envs, however that is not a real solution to your current issue.

Comment: Did you try to create a link?

Comment: @sehrob how to do that?

Comment: What is the problem? Does /usr/bin/pyang exist? If so, where does it look currently? Is pyang installed elsewhere, too? You may just need to link it.

Comment: @TheHerk It existed before I removed it using pip uninstall pyang using my current pip version (python3.2 one) as described in the question above. Now I want pyang to point to pip2.7 installed version.

Comment: @TheHerk yes, how can I link it??

Comment: `ln -s /usr/bin/pyang /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyang/bin/pyang` or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyang/bin/pyang /usr/bin/pyang
```

If this works, I think the question needs to be changed. You are asking how to make a soft link.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that you have installed `pyang` using pip2.7, and you are again trying to install it using the same pip - pip2.7. So the result is obvious. But if you only want to access `pyang` from `/usr/bin/pyang` then you can create a soft link to your existing library like this:

`ln -s /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyang/bin/pyang /usr/bin/pyang`